# chrome/opera linkedin triggers high cpu level

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, fan, cpu-load, opera

I have been using Linkedin from both Opera and Chrome (also Chromium) on Ubuntu both 18.04 and 20.04). I usually keep many tabs open and checking with the Task Manager when I open Linkedin the CPU usage goes insane (80% or more) and the fans start spinning. As soon as I kill the Linkedin tab, the usage comes back to normal again.

See the task manager (almost all the memory is used by just 1 tab , linkedin). Also the javascript memory is quit high. Is there a way to limit that?

[image]

I have this problem for a while and anytime I try to look for a solution I cannot find one.

Comment: The solution is to start block-listing some of the URLs that do nothing but serve poorly-written JavaScript trackers. Ditch Google Analytics, anything Facebook, TikTok, and the like. These "metrics collection tools" do nothing but waste your time and power. Heck, they consume more power globally than Bitcoin mining. Once you take control of what code is allowed to run in your browser you'll find your computer is much faster, much quieter, and much cooler 

Comment: Although I agree overall , unfortunately it does not solve my problem. I do not even use Facebook etc.

Comment: If you think you do not use Facebook, you've never looked at what companies your browser is sending data to. By using LinkedIn, you are giving Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Twitter, TikTok, and a whole host of advertising companies all sorts of data about how long you're on the site, where your mouse hovers the longest, which pages you view, when you scroll, how you scroll, ... the list is as long as it is offensive. What you do on a corporate site is being monitored by at least 5 big companies whether you like it or not. Take control of your browser, or it will control you.